# Absolutely continuous and derivative of measure

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\mu$ be a Borel measure on $[1,2]$ such that $\mu(a,b)=Ln(b)-Ln(a)$ for every $a,b\in[1,2]$.Show that $\mu<<\lambda$,where $\lambda$ is the lebesgue measure,and find $d\mu/d\lambda$.

If we can prove that $\mu<<\lambda$,then we can define $h(x)=\mu[1,x]$.So we know for bounded interval $[a,b]$ in $[1,2]$ we have $\int_{[a,b]} h'(x)d\lambda=\mu([a,b])$.And this quality is valid for every borel set in $[1,2]$.$d\mu/d\lambda=\dfrac{1}{x}$.I don't know how to prove the $\mu$ is absolutely continuous with respect to $\lambda$.

Comment: you have to show $\lambda(E) = 0 \Rightarrow \mu(E)=0$, see here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_continuity

Comment: Does this mean $\ln b - \ln a?$

Answer (score 1):

If you want to directly prove it, you can suppose $\lambda(E)=0$. Take a cover of $E$ by open intervals $I_k$ with $\sum_k \lambda(I_k)<\epsilon$. Find a bound for $\sum_k \mu(I_k)$ (probably something like $\sum_k \mu(I_k) < C \epsilon$). Conclude that $\mu(E)=0$.

If you want to indirectly prove it, you can just note that you've already written down $\frac{d \mu}{d \lambda}$, and therefore if $\lambda(E)=0$ then $\mu(E)=\int_E \frac{d \mu}{d \lambda} d \lambda = 0$.

Comment: In fact $\mu ((a,b)) \le b-a.$